# What's a $2$-generator submodule?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Context:

> Let $R$ be a local ring and $M$ an $R$-module. Show that the set of all submodules of $M$ is totally ordered by inclusion iff every finitely generated submodule of $M$ is cyclic or, equivalently, iff every $2$-generator submodule is cyclic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A submodule that is generated by two elements.  (This isn't exactly a standard or well-known term, but in that context there's nothing else it could sensibly mean.)

Comment: But doesn't cyclic mean that it's generated by a single element?

Comment: As in, can a module be generated both by $2$ and by $1$ element?

Comment: The abelian group $\mathbb{Z}$ is generated by $\{2,3\}$, but it is also generated by $\{1\}$.  More generally, a module can have generating sets of many different sizes (for instance, the entire module is always a generating set).

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt: He who can do the more can do the less.  (In this context, more is less and vice-versa :o))